# Role authorization throws "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Windows authentication. If I use `[Authorize]` alone everything is fine, however, if I decorate my controller with `[Authorize(Roles = "GlobalAdmin")]` authorisation fails.

This happens in both dev on my local, and after deployment on an intranet.

I definitely have the right roles assigned, because the following works fine:

```
if(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name), "GlobalAdmin"))
{
    return View();
}
```

But I don't want to have to do this on every method in my controller, and I can't use it in a constructor on a base controller because `User.Identity` returns null in a constructor.

And using the following, `var y` shows me my correct roles

```
var x = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
var y = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(x);
```

In the past I was able to create a custom override on the `Authorize` attribute and I did my own role validation in there, but core 3.1 seems to have changed methods so they aren't there to override.

But why doesn't the `[Authorize]` attribute work for my roles in the first place?

In my startup I have

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.\\";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnString")));

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
 }
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseMiddleware<Helpers.ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<Helpers.ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

The entire stacktrace looks like this:

> Win32Exception: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
>
> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, out bool someFailed)
> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, out bool someFailed)
> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, bool forceSuccess)
> System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(string role)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.RolesAuthorizationRequirement+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(string r)
> System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.RolesAuthorizationRequirement.HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationHandler.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Infrastructure.PassThroughAuthorizationHandler.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource, IEnumerable requirements)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object resource)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto done! All I can find online with the top errors are people unable to use `IsInRole` but `IsInRole` works fine for me, I just don't get why the `Authorize` attribute doesn't.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, later in the day I'll look into the source code to try to find the differences

Comment: Your code has the attribute as `[Authorization(Roles = "GlobalAdmin")]`, but the documentation shows it as `[Authorize(Roles = "GlobalAdmin")]`, have you tried this?  [Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#adding-role-checks)

Comment: @queue sorry, that was a hand-typed error, it's actually decorated with [Authorize] as it should be, I just typed "Authorization" because that's the namespace. I've typed both about 20 times this morning on google so I'm getting confusde!

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'd be very appreciative if you managed to spot the error! I'm sure I've created and used this exact project setup before without issues but that may have been with logins instead of windows auth

Comment: Can you check your output window? It seems to me that when you call you store methods you're actually calling your database rather than ActiveDirectory

Comment: Yes, I've been struggling with that, I realised me creating roles in the code is using the Asp.Net Identity tables in the database when actually I should be creating users and roles in IIS? So when I tried that, it seems my issue is that my IIS server won't actually let me create users and roles (another question I think!). The roles I'm pulling using `IsInRole` is from the DB but `[Authorize]` must be using IIS (in which there are none defined)

Comment: If you are actually on a domain then you would create user security groups there, if you are not on a domain then you would create user groups in your local system using Computer Management > Local Users and Groups.

Comment: What a learning journey I've had this weekend!! I ended up creating my own `[Authorize]` style attribute because it's much easier for me to create users and roles on a database than it is to use AD. I tried `ClaimsTransformation` to rely solely on the database using the existing `[Authorize]`, but I would still have to create groups in AD for it to work because of a bug. So in the end easier to just hijack the `OnAuthorization` method and completely ignore security groups! :/ :/

Answer (score 2):

#### TL:DR;

The error

> The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

> System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, out bool someFailed)

was simply down to the group not existing on the local system. Once the group was created **in the right place**, even if it had no members, I stopped getting this particular error.

For development, I had to create my group on my local system, as clued in by @queue in the comments. But it didn't solve my long-term issue - I wanted to use roles defined in the Database!

#### Long explanation:

I didn't understand the difference between `AspNetIdentity` and `Authorization` / `Authentication`

I'd created a default Windows Authentication app, and ended up creating `AspNetIdentity` tables as part of my initial code-first migrations so I would have database visibility of my users and could create some extra tables to relate to them. I thought these were intrinsically linked but `Identity` and `Authorisation` can exist without each other completely.

I'd used `AspNetIdentity` classes `UserManager` and `RoleManager` to create users and roles in the database, and `userManager.IsInRoleAsync(<username>)` would show all correct roles entries.

I wanted to use the `[Authorize]` attribute but I wanted it to ignore Active Directory - it seems to be a faff to set up both in dev and on my iis server, I'd need to rely on higher powers and bother other people. I just wanted it to look at the database roles.

I tried to use an `IClaimsTransformation` class with `[Authorize(Roles = "")]` which converts roles from the database in to a proper claim for use by the Windows Authentication. There are a few examples of this on StackOverflow but I kept getting the same error; Windows `[Authorization]` will fail immediately before it triggers the `ClaimsTransformation` if the group you're checking for doesn't exist in the system - even if you're going on to ignore them.

There was no order combo of the services in the Startup that would circumvent this.

I ended up using the same solution I did on previous asp.net core apps but slightly different for 3.1:

Created my own Attribute to replace [Authorize] for the top of my controllers

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RolesAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RolesAttribute(string roles) : base(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { roles };
    }
}
```

And created a simple class that luckily allows me to inject my `ApplicationDbContext` where I have a method that gets a list of roles names for a given username.

```
public class ClaimRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{

    private readonly string _roles;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ClaimRequirementFilter(string roles, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _roles = roles;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {

        List<string> matchingRoles = _context.CheckRoles(context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, roles);
        if(matchingRoles.Count == 0) context.Result = new ForbidResult();

    }
}
```

Injecting `UserManager` would possibly work too but with the async methods it'd mess up the `OnAuthorization` method so I stuck with my app context which has the AspNetIdentity tables readily accessible anyway.

Comment: +1 "I had to create the group on my local system" - works for me on the days I'm working remote and not connected to the domain